# Forecasting with lower frequency independent

Tags: time-series

I'm trying to forecast a time series variable that was sampled on a weekly frequency. All of the potential independent variables I'm considering are also available on a weekly frequency.

The catch is that the independent variable forecasts are only available on a monthly basis. This is also the frequency that the model forecast will be reported.

Is there an approach that would let me take advantage of my higher frequency dataset while also capable of generate forecasts at a lower frequency?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches. Let's say $y_t,x_{it}$ are dependent and independent variables available historically.

One way is to develop a model which forecasts at weekly frequency, then down sample (aggregate) the forecast to monthly. You'll need to up sample (interpolate) $x_{i,t+h}$ independent variables between month ends to weekly forecasts.

The other way is to build the model at monthly frequency. Instead of having one series as above, you'll have four series $y_{k+t},x_{i,k+t}$, where $k=0,1,2,3$. You'll use all four series to get the estimate of model parameters. This way you have a monthly forecasting model.

Comment: Could you expand on the second approach? I don't quite understand the reasoning behind making four series. Does $k$ represent the week within the month?

Comment: If you estimate a model at monthly frequency, then your series could be t=Jan 1, Feb 1, Mar 1, Apr 1 etc. The problem is that you'll be using only 25% of your data. That's why you have three other series such as Jan 8, Feb 8, Mar 8... , and Jan 15, Feb 15, Mar 15...

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having trouble understanding how this approach works. Do you estimate 4 models, or 1? If there is only one time series model, what are the dependent and independent variables?

Comment: You estimate one model, of course, but using 4 series. If it's OLS, then you can simply merge the series, with ARIMA it's a bit trickier